# How to create cyclic references that still get garbage collected out of scope?

Tags: python, garbage-collection

This is the test setup:

```py
import weakref, gc

class A:
    pass

def test():
    a = A()
    b = A()
    b.a = a
    return weakref.ref(a), weakref.ref(b)

r1, r2 = test()
print(r1(), r2())
# None, None

def test2():
    a = A()
    a.b = b = A()
    b.a = a
    return weakref.ref(a), weakref.ref(b)

r1, r2 = test2()
print(r1(), r2())
# <__main__.A object at 0x7f2c2521de80> <__main__.A object at 0x7f2c3404ef28>
```

I'd expect that since both `a` and `b` are out of scope that they'd be garbage collected and disappear. But because they both hold references to eachother it seems like they keep eachother alive.

How can I keep cyclic references in objects but still have them disappear out of scope?

Comment: That looks like expected behavior. Reference counting can not deal with loops, so it requires a traversing garbage collection cycle to reclaim them, which will happen when triggering it explicitly or shortly before running out of memory.

Comment: @Holger Not just shortly before running out of memory. Default threshold for generation 0 is 700 (at least in my Python), so I can trigger with just a few hundred empty lists, which is just a few dozen kB.

Comment: @HeapOverflow admittedly, I don’t know what thresholds exist in Python. I wanted to say, before you’re running out of memory, there will be a garbage collection attempt for sure and that’s all that matters.

Answer (score 0):

The garbage collector doesn't run all the time, only occasionally or when you ask for it. Try running `gc.collect()` before the final `print`. Or `[[] for _ in range(gc.get_threshold()[0])]`, that should also trigger it (it worked for me in your example, but if the objects are in generation 1 or 2 already, this might not suffice). Though I just mean that to illustrate the process, not suggesting to actually use that in production :-)

Comment: Is there no way to obtain the preferred behavior of them dissapearing together with their scoped variable? Marking them, setting some option somewhere?

Comment: Isn't `[[] for _ in range(10000)]` very unconventional and inefficient?

Comment: @RobinDeSchepper Yes, I guess I should clarify that I meant that only to illustrate the "occasionally" :-)

Comment: In my case they also contain references to objects of a C extension, a simulator. As long as there are objects in Python with references to these C pointers they remain in the simulation. When the simulation starts with C pointers that form a cycle the extension segfaults. It's a network simulator so having the Python representations reference each other makes the network theory stuff alot easier, but it means that I might create loops and start the simulation in a botched state. My only solution would be to make sure all paths toward "start simulation" garbage collect first :/

Comment: Being able to just say "hey whenever you change scope also gc these objects" would have been nice

Comment: I don't think that exists, there's just reference counting and garbage collection, the former doesn't apply and the latter happens occasionally or when requested. I guess you could create an intermediate object between your Python objects and your C objects, so that this intermediate object is the only one having references to the C objects. And then when you leave scope and want to let them go, delete those references to the C objects. The intermediate object itself will stay alive due to the reference cycles, but the C objects should get deleted right away thanks to reference counting.

Comment: Yea that's basically what I'm doing, but I still have to manually chase after garbage collection by deleting my intermediate objects which is what I wanted to avoid. But no probs, I'll clean up before I start the sim, thanks for lending me your brain ;)